# How to determine the last "x" used in curve() in R

Tags: r, function, curve

Although, one must always themselves determine the range of `x` when using `curve()` in R, I was wondering how I could get the last `x` used (i.e., `to =`) after a `curve()` is executed in R?

For example, if I save a `curve()` as an object called `cc`, I can get the first `x` (i.e., `from =`) from the `curve()` using:   `cc$x[1]` (**see below**). But how can I get the last `x` used in this `curve()`?

As an example ]

```
cc = curve(dchisq(6, df = 3, ncp = x ), from = 0, to = 10, col = 'red')

First.x.used.in.curve = cc$x[1]

Last.x.used.in.curve = ?     ## How can I find this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `tail` to get the last `n` elements of the vector `cc$x`

```
tail(x = cc$x, n = 1)
#[1] 10
```

Other possible ways would be

```
rev(cc$x)[1] #Reverse and access the first element of the reversed vector
#[1] 10

#OR

cc$x[length(cc$x)] #Index the last element by using the length of the vector
#[1] 10
```

Comment: Dear d.b, do you think you could possibly answer [**THIS QUESTION**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688786/scaling-up-a-curve-line-such-that-it-can-be-shown-along-side-another-curve-line)?